AWS DMS failing on second run due to Athena permissions
DMS is producing this error on the second run. Can't work out why, I've not even said for Athena to be used.
2024-09-18T15:49:45 [TARGET_APPLY    ]I:  Key len for get: 17 for table `(null)`.`(null)`  (file_glue_catalog_generation.c:296)
2024-09-18T15:49:45 [TASK_MANAGER    ]E:  Not retriable error: <InvalidRequestException> line 1:8: mismatched input 'DATABASE'. Expecting: 'MATERIALIZED', 'MULTI', 'OR', 'PROTECTED', 'ROLE', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW' [1001730]  (anw_retry_strategy.cpp:118)
2024-09-18T15:49:45 [TASK_MANAGER    ]E:  The athena start query execution request failed: line 1:8: mismatched input 'DATABASE'. Expecting: 'MATERIALIZED', 'MULTI', 'OR', 'PROTECTED', 'ROLE', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW' [1001804]  (athena_client.cpp:439)
2024-09-18T15:49:45 [TARGET_APPLY    ]E:  Failed to create Athena Database (null) [2]  (file_glue_catalog_generation.c:326)
2024-09-18T15:49:45 [TARGET_APPLY    ]I:  Error in bulk, bulk state: bulk confirmed record id - '0', bulk last record id - '0', confirmed record id - '10517', sorter confirmed record id - '10517'  (bulk_apply.c:2993)```


The first run works? What is your Target database?

Yeah the first run goes fine. The target is S3. Maybe it's using Athena to establish where it's up to, as I'm doing full load + CDC?

Can you give some steps to reproduce the error?

A bit more background: I'm running multiple DMS tasks against a single DMS instance. This is in the development phase and I'm trying to determine the smallest server I can get away with. Due to this, if my initial replication cuts out due to out of memory error, on the second run when I try to resume it, it fails with this error.

Seems to be related to the glue data catalog, since it works when I disable that. The glue data catalog does populate fine, it just seems to cause issues when a second run is being executed.

DMS could be using Glue for schema conversion, and this might attempt to create an Athena database. Verify the Glue Catalog configurations within the DMS task. Ensure no unintended settings are trying to generate databases.
